# Server.MapPath Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an error on the the file path to create the log file. I need to use `Server.MapPath` to implement a correct path but have never used one. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(
                    Path.Combine(LogExtensionConfigSettings.LogFilePath, 
                                 "VanickWebServiceLogger.txt"), 
                                 FileMode.Append, 
                                 FileAccess.Write);
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I think it is getting confused by the ~ in the path. Here is the error.

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\App_Data\VanickWebServiceLogger.txt'.

Comment: @KevinSchultz It looks like you're combining physical and virtual path in `LogExtensionConfigSettings.LogFilePath`.  Pick one or the other.

Comment: As with what @DStanley said, what is the value of your `LogExtensionConfigSettings.LogFilePath`? It should either by just a Virtual Path i.e. `~/App_Data/` or a Physical Path `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Project\App_Data\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Server.MapPath` maps a *virtual* file path to a *physical* one - if `LogFilePath` is *already* a physical path them `MapPath` in unnecessary.

If it's a *virtual* path then just call `Server.MapPath` on the virtual path:

```
string path = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(LogExtensionConfigSettings.LogFilePath, 
                                 "VanickWebServiceLogger.txt");

FileStream fs = new FileStream(  path, 
                                 FileMode.Append, 
                                 FileAccess.Write);
```

Note that you should also enclose the FileStream in a `using` statement to ensire it gets closed if there is an exception:

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, 
                                     FileMode.Append, 
                                     FileAccess.Write)
{
    // do stuff 
}
```

Comment: Trying to implement your answer and Server.MapPath is not recognized. I have the System.Web using statement? Is there another I should implement?

Comment: Typically it is used in the code-behind of a page - `Server` is a property of the `Page` class.

Comment: You might be able to use `HttpContext.Current.Server` (*if* you are in an http context)

Comment: Had to manipulate it, but this works great. Thanks for the assistance.